# SharePoint 2016 + WAP + ADFS using SAML, make sense?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, adfs, saml

is it make sense to use SAML in SharePoint 2016 + WAP + ADFS?
how will the authentication request flow will looks like?

I m a newb for sharepoint using Window Authentication, now my comp want use ADFS and WAP as the sharepoint will going to accessible from internet(for employee work from home with their own pc without use of VPN)...

searching around for few days end up, confusing if this combination is correct in any sense, please help me

Answer (score 2):

This scenario makes sense and it gives you more security.

**Why use WAP on-top of SharePoint & ADFS?**

Because it gives you a way of exposing your public SharePoint applications to the internet without anyone having any line-of-sight. This is important because it means nobody could overwhelm your SharePoint infrastructure without being authenticated first.

Read more about

- [Publishing SharePoint with Windows Server 2012 R2 Web Application Proxy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/12/10/publishing-sharepoint-with-windows-server-2012-r2-web-application-proxy/)
- and [SharePoint Server and Web Application Proxy – continued](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2015/07/01/sharepoint-server-and-web-application-proxy-continued/)

on Windows Server 2016, please read this

- [SharePoint + Web Application Proxy – 2016 Edition](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2017/04/04/sharepoint-web-application-proxy-2016-edition/)